# I am attempting to use setState in React

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I'm attempting to use setState function to a method in my App class..

example of the current code:

```
addRandomContact() {
this.setState({
  actors: contacts.slice(0, 6)
})
```

}

I am expecting my contacts array to change from a length of 5 to 6.

The error I am receiving is the following:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
addRandomContact

Comment: How is `addRandomContact()` called? It looks like you lost the `this` binding.

Comment: We need to see the context of this function, the error suggests it's not inside of a react component.

Comment: Slicing an array won't increase it's length. Try `[...Array(5).keys()].slice(0, 6)` in your console. `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` is result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"this" keyword will not be accessible inside this function and hence its undefined.
You have to use arrow function like below:

```
addRandomContact = () => {
this.setState({
  actors: contacts.slice(0, 6)
})
```

Comment: "Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined addRandomContact" should be resolved using arrow functions.

Comment: How can you answer when there is minimal context around where and how `addRandomContact` is defined, or where it's being called?

Comment: It looked as a syntactical error in defining functions.

Comment: Syntax is fine. `this` just isn't the `this` of the `App` component. There are ways other than using an arrow function, BTW. Bound in component constructor or bound when invoked. Your answer isn't technically wrong, but doesn't adequately address *why* OP has an issue to begin with.

Comment: Agreed , alternatively we could also bind the method in constructor.

Comment: And in the question , the issue was that "this" was undefined and hence the error. That is what I have explained.

Comment: Thank you Sallu! This worked. Sorry for the minimal context, I'm new to stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's not very clear from your given codebase what is the issue but one possible error you could make is that you are not binding `addRandomContact` inside constructor of that class component. Try to paste the following code in your constructor and check if it solves

```
this.addRandomContact = this.addRandomContact.bind(this);
```